# Selenium Chromedriver error code : 3221225477

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When initiating chromedriver with selenium in python 3,
everything seems to go okay for at least one second while it loads,
but then this error message pops up :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Selenium\UsingChrome.py3", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriverwin32.exe")
  File "c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "c:\Users\...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriverwin32.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225477
```

My current code is :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time, os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = 'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://python.org')
```

... I've tried using an absolute path for the chromedriver location, but that still doesn't help (the chromedriver.exe file is located in the same directory as the script)

- I'm running this on python 3.6.5 on a Windows 10 laptop
- I've already been searching around on the web for about 3 hours but haven't come across the same error status code that I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is really weird.
Chromedriver selenium worked perfectly when launching it in an interactive shell, but not when executing the script.
On my machine, I've setup a few batch files which are executed when a python script is executed (to run things like Ansicon.exe for colour display in cmd), and after running the python script with the command 'python3 script.py' it works perfectly...
So I'm not sure why it didn't before, but anyhow, it's fixed now.

- But if anyone does have an answer, I'd love to know why this happened...

My code is now :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
while 1: pass # wait forever just to let chromedriver be interactive
```

and the batch file to start is one line :

```
python3 script.py
```